# Triggering jQuery function at end of callback assistance?

Tags: jquery, ajax

I clearly do not understand jQuery asynchronous execution properly. I have the following issue. I have a function that changes a select list as follows:

```
function loadGroups() {

$.getJSON("/Process/ShowGroups", null, function (data) {
    var selectList = $("#groupsList");
    selectList.empty();
    $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
        var option = $('<option>').text(optionData.Text).val(optionData.Value);
        selectList.append(option);
    });
});
$("#groupsList").trigger("liszt:updated");
}
```

I am using a control which needs to be alerted AFTER the list has been updated so that it can refresh the contents. I need to trigger

```
$("#groupsList").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Now this seems to make sense to me but I was informed that this is a part of the same callback and I need to move it to the end of the callback function. Fair enough, I then tried this:

```
loadGroups();
$("#groupsList").trigger("liszt:updated");
```

Which seems like it should work. The loadGroups() does the change. Shouldn't the `callback` be done after the function is called? What am I missing? How can I ensure that the loadGroups is done before I trigger the event?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should trigger it in the `getJSON` callback. Try this

```
function loadGroups() {

$.getJSON("/Process/ShowGroups", null, function (data) {
    var selectList = $("#groupsList");
    selectList.empty();
    $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
        var option = $('<option>').text(optionData.Text).val(optionData.Value);
        selectList.append(option);
    });
    $("#groupsList").trigger("liszt:updated");
});

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Well the ajax is still running asynchronously so doing that won't solve the problem. There a few solutions:

You could, move the trigger code into the callback itself. This works but is tightly coupling your ajax request with the trigger code, this would call the trigger every time you call loadGroups().

```
function loadGroups() {
   $.getJSON("/Process/ShowGroups", null, function (data) {
       var selectList = $("#groupsList");
       selectList.empty();
       $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
           var option = $('<option>').text(optionData.Text).val(optionData.Value);
           selectList.append(option);
       });
       $("#groupsList").trigger("liszt:updated");
   });
}
```

You could pass in a callback as an argument to the function. This is a little more flexible as you can call other functions and not just the trigger code.

```
function loadGroups(callback) {
   $.getJSON("/Process/ShowGroups", null, function (data) {
       var selectList = $("#groupsList");
       selectList.empty();
       $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
           var option = $('<option>').text(optionData.Text).val(optionData.Value);
           selectList.append(option);
       });
       if( typeof callback === 'function' )
           callback(); 
   });
}
```

Then

```
  loadGroups( function(){ $("#groupsList").trigger("liszt:updated"); } );
```

You could use the new jQuery deffered API to perform whatever you need once the ajax request has completed.

```
function loadGroups() {
   return $.getJSON("/Process/ShowGroups", null, function (data) {
       var selectList = $("#groupsList");
       selectList.empty();
       $.each(data, function (index, optionData) {
           var option = $('<option>').text(optionData.Text).val(optionData.Value);
           selectList.append(option);
       });

   });
}
```

Then to use the function

```
$.when( loadGroups() ).then(function(){ $("#groupsList").trigger("liszt:updated"); });
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code will be executed following this order:

1. $.getJSON("/Process/ShowGroups"...
2. Server call to the url. The client wont wait for the response from server.
3. Any code after the $.getJSON, into the loadGroups function.
4. When the server sends response (probabily after the step 3), your callback function will execute. So any code that must be executed AFTER the response must be placed into the callback function (the 3rd argument of the $.getJSON call).